# strange python behaviour with mixing globals/parameters and function named 'top'

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code (not directly in an interpreter, but execute as file)

```
def top(deck):
    pass

def b():
    global deck
```

produces the error

```
SyntaxError: name 'deck' is local and global
```

on python2.6.4 and

```
SyntaxError: name 'deck' is parameter and global
```

on python 3.1

python2.4 seems to accept this code, so does the 2.6.4 interactive interpreter.

This is already odd; why is 'deck' conflicting if it's a global in one method and a parameter in the other?

But it gets weirder. Rename 'top' to basically anything else, and the problem disappears.

Can someone explain this behaviour? I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here. Is the name 'top' somehow affecting certain scoping internals?

**Update**

This indeed appears to be a bug in the python core. [I have filed a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue9997).

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm this behavior in 2.6.5 and 3.1.2.

Comment: Adding `print top` yields "name 'top' is not defined", so at least it's not a function or something. Odd.

Comment: @Aaron indeed, tried that as well.

Comment: Exchanging the two methods also fixes the problem (`b` first, then `top`).

Comment: From the source code (http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/symtable.c), it seems that the parser somehow thinks the body of `b` is part of the function body of `top` (i.e. that the parameter and the global are in the same scope).

Comment: Can anyone find another name besides `top` that triggers the bug? For the record, `id` and `hash` of top don't look odd (3074663844=0xb74465a4, -1220303452=-0x48bb9a5c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug in the symbol table handling. Python/symtable.c has some code that (although somewhat obfuscated) does indeed treat 'top' as a special identifier:

```
if (!GET_IDENTIFIER(top) ||
    !symtable_enter_block(st, top, ModuleBlock, (void *)mod, 0)) {
    PySymtable_Free(st);
    return NULL;
}
```

followed somewhat later by:

```
if (name == GET_IDENTIFIER(top))
    st->st_global = st->st_cur->ste_symbols;
```

Further up the file there's a macro:

```
#define GET_IDENTIFIER(VAR) \
    ((VAR) ? (VAR) : ((VAR) = PyString_InternFromString(# VAR)))
```

which uses the C preprocessor to initialise the variable `top` to an interned string with the name of the variable.

I think the symbol table must be using the name 'top' to refer to the top level code, but why it doesn't use something that can't conflict with a real variable I have no idea.

I would report it as a bug if I were you.

Comment: -1 Can't follow you. The runtime assembler code can't see that the variable was called "top" in the source. This would be different if there was a string `"top"` anywhere.

Comment: The macro effectively boils down to: `((top)?(top):((top)=PyString_InternFromString("top")))`  (the C pre-processor syntax # VAR means turn the value of the macro parameter into a string)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it looks as if "top" gets defined by accident as the global name space identifier. If the variable in C code was named _cookies, the conflict would be with a function named _cookies.

Comment: The name of the variable in the C code doesn't really matter, that's just how the macro works. It could (and should!) use `'top'` as the C variable but `" o/~ la la teeny tiny puppies... o/~ "` as the Python symbol... Or at least something that is in no way a valid Python symbol ;P

Comment: Yes, I maybe wasn't clear enough that I was referring to the value of `top` as being the problem rather than the name. BTW, symtable.py also has special knowledge of this name though the fundamental problem is in the C code.