# How I could turn this Python code into a function?

Tags: python

I have this code that I want to turn into a function. I need function_text to be accessible outside the function.

```
   function_text = TextClip(item_1, fontsize=main_text_size, font=main_font, color=corner_text_color, size=(w, text_size_60))
   function_text = function_text.set_fps(fps)
   function_text = function_text.set_duration(5)
   function_text = function_text.margin(left=0, right=1300, top=950, opacity=0)
   function_text = function_text.set_position(("center"))
```

I want to be able to enter a variable name(function_text), and margin attribute with values to that variable(4th line in the code)

This is where I am at right now:

```
def displayText(my_str):
   global my_str
   my_str = TextClip(item_1, fontsize=main_text_size, font=main_font, color=corner_text_color, size=(w, text_size_60))
   my_str = my_str.set_fps(fps)
   my_str = my_str.set_duration(5)
   my_str = my_str.margin(left=0, right=1300, top=950, opacity=0)
   my_str = my_str.set_position(("center"))
   return
displayText("function_text")
```

The problem I get is that I can't set my parameter as global because I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: name 'my_str' is parameter and global
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18807749/4985099

Comment: is the passing parameter you want is a string? or integer

Comment: I am not sure but I think it's different because in that post person wants to use input for data, I want to pass it through function parameters.

Comment: I want to pass a name for a variable to use in the function and then I want that variable to be accessible outside the function.

Comment: @TomBelevic that is not how you should organize your functions. And that isn't how parameters work. Instead, you should think of your functions as accepting values and returning values.

Comment: Thank you, juanpa. I get that I was thinking completely out of wrong and more complicated perspective. Now that I know the answer it seems very obvious and a lot more practical to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `my_str` as both a global variable and a paramater. You can only use it one way. From your code it looks like you don't actually need to read in `my_str` (in the first line of the function you assign to it a new value), so returning it should suffice:

```
def displayText():
   my_str = TextClip(item_1, fontsize=main_text_size, font=main_font, color=corner_text_color, size=(w, text_size_60))
   my_str = my_str.set_fps(fps)
   my_str = my_str.set_duration(5)
   my_str = my_str.margin(left=0, right=1300, top=950, opacity=0)
   my_str = my_str.set_position(("center"))
   return my_str
function_text = displayText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use global variables (ever).
The error is because you set the same name for your global variable and for your parameter name, both are 'my_str'.

> def displayText( **my_str** ):

And then inside of the function,  where **my_str** already exist because it was passed as a parameter, you are defining **my_str** again, this is wrong as it already was defined previously.

just delete

> global **my_str**

and add:

```
return my_str
```

at the end of the function