# How to pass and return dataframe by reference in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function called ChangeDF

```
def ChangeDF(df)
    df = df[["Col1","Col2"]]


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "One", "Hello"], [2, "Two", "Hi"]], columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
ChangeDF(df)
print(df)
```

it suppose to remove one column in datafeame

But I want to change the actual dataframe when call ChangeDF function

When I do now , it just create another instance of df

how can I cange it by reference not by value?

the df should print

```
1 One
2 Two
```

not

```
1 One Hello
2 Two Hi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use the `drop()` method and set `inplace=True`:

```
def ChangeDF(df):
    df.drop(["Col3"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "One", "Hello"], [2, "Two", "Hi"]], columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
ChangeDF(df)
print(df)
```

Comment: he doesn't want to return, he wants to modify the original df

Comment: there should be no RETURN. it is call by reference

Comment: @asmgx I updated my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

The pandas tends to default to copy-and-modify instead of in-place operations. If following this convention, then

```
def ChangeDF(df)
    return df[["Col1","Col2"]]

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "One", "Hello"], [2, "Two", "Hi"]], columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
df = ChangeDF(df)
```

Or, if you really want in-place, then

```py
def ChangeDFInPlace(df)
    to_remove = [x for x in df.columns if x not in ("Col1", "Col2")]
    df.drop(to_remove, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the data frame in global namespace. As you can't assign a [function parameter as global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807749/name-x-is-parameter-and-global-python), you need to define a function inside the ChangeDF function.

```
import pandas as pd

def ChangeDF(df):
    def change_global():
        global df
        df = df[["Col1","Col2"]]
    change_global()


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "One", "Hello"], [2, "Two", "Hi"]], columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
ChangeDF(df)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Col1 Col2
    0     1  One
    1     2  Two
```